# how can i solve sigmoid function?

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics, education

$$\frac{1}{ 1-e^ {-(-3.0)}} = -0.052$$

$-0.052$ is the answer. This equation is sigmoid function. How could I get the answer like that? Please understand me T.T

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you are trying ot "solve"?

Comment: how could I get the answer, -0.052? What's the process to solve the equation?

Comment: The answer is given. But I don't know how this answer got out.

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't know, $e$ is a [mathematical constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29), and its approximate value is $e\approx2.718$. Applying it, we have:

$$\frac{1}{1-e^{-(-3.0)}}=\frac{1}{1-e^3}=\frac{1}{1-\left(2.718\right)^{3}}=-0.0524128512.$$